# how to use click in this jquery

Tags: jquery

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var $oe_menu = $('#oe_menu');
        var $oe_menu_items = $oe_menu.children('li');
        $oe_menu_items.bind('mouseenter', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass('selected');
            $this.children('div').css('z-index', '9999').stop(true, true).slideDown(300, function () {
                $(this).parent().not('.selected').children('div').hide();
            });
        }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).children('div').hide();
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('selected').children('div').css('z-index', '1');
        }).bind('click', function () {
            $(this).children('div').hide();
            var $this = $(this);
//          if (window.mobilecheck()) {
            $this.removeClass('selected').children('div').css('z-index', '1');
//          }
        });
        $oe_menu.bind('mouseenter', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass('hovered');

        }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('hovered');
            $this.children('div').hide();
        }).bind('click', function () {
//          if (window.mobilecheck()) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('hovered');
            $this.children('div').hide();
//          }
        });
        if ($('.grid-categories-megamenu').parent().parent()) {
            $('.grid-categories-megamenu').parent().parent().mouseenter(function () {
                height1 = $(this).attr('id');
                var max_height_title = 0;
                $.each($('#' + height1 + ' .level1-title'), function (key, e) {
                    if (max_height_title < $(this).height()) {
                        max_height_title = $(this).height();
                    }
                });
                $('#' + height1 + ' .level1-title').height(max_height_title);
                var max_height1 = 0;
                $.each($('#' + height1 + ' .level1-megamenu'), function (key, e) {
                    if (max_height1 < $(this).height()) {
                        max_height1 = $(this).height();
                    }
                });
                $('#' + height1 + ' .level1-megamenu').height(max_height1);

            });
        }
        if ($('.list-categories-megamenu').parent().parent()) {
            $('.list-categories-megamenu').parent().parent().mouseenter(function () {
                height2 = $(this).attr('id');
                var max_height2 = 0;
                $.each($('#' + height2 + ' .level1-megamenu'), function (key, e) {
                    if (max_height2 < $(this).height()) {
                        max_height2 = $(this).height();
                    }
                });
                $('#' + height2 + ' .level1-megamenu').height(max_height2);
            });
        }
        if ($('.group-category').parent().parent().parent()) {
            $('.group-category').parent().parent().parent().mouseenter(function () {
                height3 = $(this).attr('id');
                var max_height3 = 0;
                $.each($('#' + height3 + ' .level1-megamenu'), function () {
                    if (max_height3 < $(this).height()) {
                        max_height3 = $(this).height();
                    }
                });
                $('#' + height3 + ' .level1-megamenu').height(max_height3);
            });
        }
        if ($('.products-megamenu-grid').parent().parent()) {
            $('.products-megamenu-grid').parent().parent().mouseenter(function () {
                height4 = $(this).attr('id');
                var max_height_name = 0;
                $.each($('#' + height4 + ' .product-name'), function (key, e) {
                    if (max_height_name < $(this).height()) {
                        max_height_name = $(this).height();
                    }
                });
                $('#' + height4 + ' .product-name').height(max_height_name);
            });
        }
    });
```

The script above is being used to control a megamenu for a magento website. In a mobile phone view i need to be able to click to open the menu then click to close it. If possible is there away i can hide the sub-categories with a plus sign? Please adivce.

Comment: create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/myv6nzpt/ i also want it to be collapsed menu in mobile view by that i mean the submenu are hidden until the category name is clicked

Comment: I found a similiar prototype on web, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Lm30j0p3/1/ . you can use it to change your menu. hope it helps